# I keep getting undefined reference error when trying to access object of another class, anyone can help me out?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, undefined, destructor

This is the error I receive.

I created the Connected Component Class , with it's header

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an [mcve], as text in the question (use the code formatting tool), not as an image.

Comment: We can't really help. Other than closing your question for one that tries to help resolve all undefined reference errors.

Comment: If you are using VSCode remember that by default it only builds the active  file into your executable. The documentation @ github explains how to modify your tasks.json to allow for building more than 1 source file.